# how to pass values from datagridview1 in form1 to datagridview2 in form2?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have to pass some values from dataGridView1 to another form's dataGridView...

I am using a DataTable to populate all these values...

this is my data table in form1:

```
{
    table = new DataTable();

    table.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
    table.Columns.Add("ItemCode", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Amount", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(string));
}
table.Rows.Add(ID, ItemCode, ProductName, Total,qty);
dataGridView2.DataSource = table;
```

I need to populate these values into another dataGridView in form2.

All this should happen through button click event...

This is where the object reference problem starts...

```
if (dataGridView2.RowCount != 0)
{        
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)        
    {                                                   
        ((Form2)f).dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ordered Item list is Empty!");
}
```

Finally I solved it using this

```
if (dataGridView2.RowCount != 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
    {
        if (row.IsNewRow) continue;
        {
            object[] rowData = new object[row.Cells.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowData.Length; ++i)
            {
                rowData[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowData);
        }
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ordered Item list is Empty!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search will yield several posts that could be of use to your situation.  I think this one in particular would help:

[How to copy/transfer values from form2 datagridview to form1 datagridview in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627471/how-to-copy-transfer-values-from-form2-datagridview-to-form1-datagridview-in-c?rq=1)

You want it the other way around, but the idea is the same.  Form1 should have a reference to Form2.  Then you can either make the datagridview in Form2 public or provide a public method that will allow Form1 to make changes to it in the Form1 button click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Declare Form1's DGV as Public instead of private and do the following in Form2 :

Declare the following variable :

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form f = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms["Form1"];.
Do the Following changes in your program:
 private void button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)      
 {

 try
  {
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount != 0)
    {

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {                                       
            ((Form1)f).dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);                    
        }

      }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There is no data to export, please verify..!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
catch { }   }
```